# Squid proxy discarding request made with netcat, but not curl

Tags: squid, netcat

I need to make a REST call within a RHEL kickstart `%pre` script, and thus I am limited to using netcat (since the `wget` packaged in the RHEL `%pre` environment can't configure the HTTP method).  I'd of course love to use `curl` (since it has the lovely `-X` option) but alas it's not available in the `%pre` environment.

That said, here's a relevant `curl` command and, importantly, the exact stream of bytes it sends to the server:

```
$ curl -X POST http://pkrizak-globalpxe.anonycom.com/univac/api/record/pkrizak-sles10.anonycom.com/_install_log --data-binary '[ ]' --trace /tmp/foo.log
$ cat /tmp/foo.log (truncated)
== Info: About to connect() to pkrizak-globalpxe.anonycom.com port 80 (#0)
== Info:   Trying 10.46.174.117... == Info: connected
== Info: Connected to pkrizak-globalpxe.anonycom.com (10.46.174.117) port 80 (#0)
=> Send header, 312 bytes (0x138)
0000: 50 4f 53 54 20 2f 75 6e 69 76 61 63 2f 61 70 69 POST /univac/api
0010: 2f 72 65 63 6f 72 64 2f 70 6b 72 69 7a 61 6b 2d /record/pkrizak-
0020: 73 6c 65 73 31 30 2e 61 63 6f 63 79 63 6f 6d 2e sles10.anonycom.
0030: 63 6f 6d 2f 5f 69 6e 73 74 61 6c 6c 5f 6c 6f 67 com/_install_log
0040: 20 48 54 54 50 2f 31 2e 31 0d 0a 55 73 65 72 2d  HTTP/1.1..User-
0050: 41 67 65 6e 74 3a 20 63 75 72 6c 2f 37 2e 31 39 Agent: curl/7.19
0060: 2e 37 20 28 78 38 36 5f 36 34 2d 72 65 64 68 61 .7 (x86_64-redha
0070: 74 2d 6c 69 6e 75 78 2d 67 6e 75 29 20 6c 69 62 t-linux-gnu) lib
0080: 63 75 72 6c 2f 37 2e 31 39 2e 37 20 4e 53 53 2f curl/7.19.7 NSS/
0090: 33 2e 31 34 2e 33 2e 30 20 7a 6c 69 62 2f 31 2e 3.14.3.0 zlib/1.
00a0: 32 2e 33 20 6c 69 62 69 64 6e 2f 31 2e 31 38 20 2.3 libidn/1.18 
00b0: 6c 69 62 73 73 68 32 2f 31 2e 34 2e 32 0d 0a 48 libssh2/1.4.2..H
00c0: 6f 73 74 3a 20 70 6b 72 69 7a 61 6b 2d 67 6c 6f ost: pkrizak-glo
00d0: 62 61 6c 70 78 65 2e 61 63 6f 63 79 63 6f 6d 2e balpxe.anonycom.
00e0: 63 6f 6d 0d 0a 41 63 63 65 70 74 3a 20 2a 2f 2a com..Accept: */*
00f0: 0d 0a 43 6f 6e 74 65 6e 74 2d 4c 65 6e 67 74 68 ..Content-Length
0100: 3a 20 33 0d 0a 43 6f 6e 74 65 6e 74 2d 54 79 70 : 3..Content-Typ
0110: 65 3a 20 61 70 70 6c 69 63 61 74 69 6f 6e 2f 78 e: application/x
0120: 2d 77 77 77 2d 66 6f 72 6d 2d 75 72 6c 65 6e 63 -www-form-urlenc
0130: 6f 64 65 64 0d 0a 0d 0a                         oded....
=> Send data, 3 bytes (0x3)
0000: 5b 20 5d                                        [ ]
== Info: HTTP 1.0, assume close after body
<= Recv header, 24 bytes (0x18)
```

I've truncated the rest, but suffice to say that the transaction continues without problems.

Now, sending the exact same stream of bytes using netcat:

```
$ ./mypost.sh | hexdump -C
00000000  50 4f 53 54 20 2f 75 6e  69 76 61 63 2f 61 70 69  |POST /univac/api|
00000010  2f 72 65 63 6f 72 64 2f  70 6b 72 69 7a 61 6b 2d  |/record/pkrizak-|
00000020  73 6c 65 73 31 30 2e 61  63 6f 63 79 63 6f 6d 2e  |sles10.anonycom.|
00000030  63 6f 6d 2f 5f 69 6e 73  74 61 6c 6c 5f 6c 6f 67  |com/_install_log|
00000040  20 48 54 54 50 2f 31 2e  31 0d 0a 55 73 65 72 2d  | HTTP/1.1..User-|
00000050  41 67 65 6e 74 3a 20 63  75 72 6c 2f 37 2e 31 39  |Agent: curl/7.19|
00000060  2e 37 20 28 78 38 36 5f  36 34 2d 72 65 64 68 61  |.7 (x86_64-redha|
00000070  74 2d 6c 69 6e 75 78 2d  67 6e 75 29 20 6c 69 62  |t-linux-gnu) lib|
00000080  63 75 72 6c 2f 37 2e 31  39 2e 37 20 4e 53 53 2f  |curl/7.19.7 NSS/|
00000090  33 2e 31 34 2e 33 2e 30  20 7a 6c 69 62 2f 31 2e  |3.14.3.0 zlib/1.|
000000a0  32 2e 33 20 6c 69 62 69  64 6e 2f 31 2e 31 38 20  |2.3 libidn/1.18 |
000000b0  6c 69 62 73 73 68 32 2f  31 2e 34 2e 32 0d 0a 48  |libssh2/1.4.2..H|
000000c0  6f 73 74 3a 20 70 6b 72  69 7a 61 6b 2d 67 6c 6f  |ost: pkrizak-glo|
000000d0  62 61 6c 70 78 65 2e 61  63 6f 63 79 63 6f 6d 2e  |balpxe.anonycom.|
000000e0  63 6f 6d 0d 0a 41 63 63  65 70 74 3a 20 2a 2f 2a  |com..Accept: */*|
000000f0  0d 0a 43 6f 6e 74 65 6e  74 2d 6c 65 6e 67 74 68  |..Content-length|
00000100  3a 20 33 0d 0a 43 6f 6e  74 65 6e 74 2d 74 79 70  |: 3..Content-typ|
00000110  65 3a 20 61 70 70 6c 69  63 61 74 69 6f 6e 2f 78  |e: application/x|
00000120  2d 77 77 77 2d 66 6f 72  6d 2d 75 72 6c 65 6e 63  |-www-form-urlenc|
00000130  6f 64 65 64 0d 0a 0d 0a  5b 20 5d                 |oded....[ ]|
0000013b
```

...doesn't work:

```
$ ./mypost.sh | nc pkrizak-globalpxe.anonycom.com 80
$ # no response
```

The tricky bit here is that there is a squid (reverse) proxy listening on port 80 of the host I'm connecting to.  So I'm not actually talking to Apache or Nginx or even my custom Perl application -- I'm trying to talk to Squid (which when approached with `curl` actually forwards the request properly to my application).  And apparently something is different about how curl talks to Squid than how nc is talking to squid, despite the content of the request being identical.

I've tried changing the request to use `HTTP/1.0` and even tried leaving the `HTTP/` part off, but that does not help.

I'm really baffled at this point -- what is going on under the hood that I'm missing?  Why is netcat behaving differently?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out this is an oddity in the way that netcat behaves when piped data on STDIN.

After tracing the packets with wireshark, I found that netcat, after sending the data piped to STDIN, immediately sends a FIN,ACK packet to the server.  The squid server, naturally, aborts processing of the request upon receipt of the FIN,ACK packet and closes the connection.

This behavior can be avoided by using the `-i` option to netcat, which specifies an interval time between transactions.  Using `-i 1`, for example, waits one second before sending the FIN,ACK after sending its data.  This is long enough for the squid proxy to return with an answer.

Another solution is to have the script generating the input to STDIN pause after writing out the HTTP POST information.  A simple `sleep 1` at the end of the script appears to be sufficient to get the proxy to complete the request.